# How to create and use a private pod in swift 2 and XCode 7 beta 6

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swift2, xcode7-beta6

I have created a private pod library. I can use classes I created in a pod in an Example app that is pre-created with "pod lib create" command. I have pushed and tagged the library in a private git repo.
Then I create a new project, do pod init, write a Podfile with a pod reference that points to a private repo. "pod install" command reports downloading and installing the pod.
However, I can not reference or use the classes in my Demo project. What am I missing?